# How does one deal with too much missing values in a dataset for machine learning?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, missing-data

I have a column that can prove to be very important for the machine learning model I need. I have approx. 20% rows of a not too large dataset missing that column. I have tried filling it in with other values but there is no way to fill it in with reasonable values.

Answer (score 0):

till what I understood your question, I would suggest first that check the column type, either it has categorical or binary data.
if it has binary data the replace nan value with mode
**df=df['col1'].fillna(df['col1'].mode())**
and for categorical
**df=df['col1'].fillna(df['col1'].mean())**
or either drop nan value
like **dropna**

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).